# List of coordinates to Topojson

Tags: qgis, coordinates, topojson

I have a list of coordinates in Lambert Conformal Conic projection. Those coordinates draw the border of specific area.

> (179506,161069),(180016,161633),(180375,162142),...

I need to create a topojson file to use this as a map in D3.js

I found how to insert them in QGIS but after that I do not understand how to generate my topojson.

Can I do it directly in QGIS or is there an other way ?

Answer (score 2):

---

**Convert points (from a delimited layer) to polygons**

If your data is in a spreadsheet, you can import it directly with the **XYTools** plugin, without needing to export as CSV.

Then use the **Points2One** plugin on your points layer. If your points are arranged in order around the boundary you should be okay.

---

**Export to TopJSON**

There's no direct export in QGIS to TopoJSON at the moment (as of 2.16), just GeoJSON.

But there are a couple of Options open to you...

- The **D3 Map Renderer Plugin**. This lets you export TopoJSON. However it has a couple of prerequisites which [you'll need to install yourself](http://maprenderer.org/d3/) (npm, javascript topojson, a local http server). It's used to build D3 web pages, if you're comfortable with JavaScript this should give you a good start.
- Another option is [MapShaper](http://www.mapshaper.org/). This is a site that lets you load in shapefiles and export topoJSON. Got some useful features like the ability to tweak the detail level (simplification) to get file sizes down further, and can attempt to fix geometries too :)

Comment: Points2One seems to work well if I do it polygon by polygon but then how can I concatenate it ? If I first concatenate all my csv files in one it will draw the polygons + some random lines

Answer (score 1):

I've just done a quick google and [found this blog](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/06/converting-shapefiles-to-topojson.html) that converts shp to topojson.  By the looks of it, it can all be done through the command line.

Comment: And how can I get this shapefile ? With my coordinates ?

Comment: If your coordinates are in a csv you can load them straight into QGIS using 'Add delimited text layer'.  Else create a csv in excel with two columns (x, y) and split out the coordinates in your list into their respective columns, then load into qgis and save that out as a shapefile

Comment: I have multiple csv file (1 by polygon) - When importing in QGIS I got multiple layers. Should I export them one by one ?

Comment: It could be a pain if you have many files to import into QGIS but save each one out as a shp and under 'Vector > Data Management Tools > Merge Vector Layers' you can create a single shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line tool here: https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference

That's what I'd do:

1. Create the polygon in QGIS (see other answers)
2. Export as SHP
3. Use topojson command line tool to change from SHP to TopoJSON (play with quantisation to optimise file size.

You could try directly reading the CSV using TopoJSON, but I'm not sure if it handles your list of coordinates as a polygon.